# javascript change function parameter variable name and return its value

Tags: javascript, function, variables, parameters

Hi i have a function and i want to return the function parameter with an added value to the parameter. So instead of writing this:

```
function(response) {
    return response.links_1;
}

function(response) {
    return response.links_2;
}

function(response) {
    return response.links_3;
}
```

I want to make a for loop that iterates through and adds the number, something like this:

```
function(response) {
    var counter = 3;
    for(var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        return response.links_ +i;
    }
}
```

The important part is that response.link_ must not be a string! 
Then it looses the function parameter value.

I tried with doing this:

```
function(response) {
    var i = 1,  
    resp = 'response.links_',
    endResp = resp + i;
    return endResp ;
    }
}
```

And console.log(endResp); returns the correct string, but thats just it, its a string.. i want the value of the **variable** response.links_1 not the string value response.links_1.

I have just tried the following without any luck:  (the parse: is just a backbone method)

```
parse: function(response) {
    var counter = 3;
 for(var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
   return response[links_ + i];
}
}
```

Any help is welcome..

Comment: yeah i tested with eval() and same effect - but it could just be, im not doing it correctly.

Comment: please explain what on earth it is you're trying to do!  You can't `return` in a loop to get "n" results - on the first `return` the entire function will finish!  This is what we call an "XY problem" - you're asking a non-sensical question because somewhere _before_ this you've made a design error, so your analysis of what you think you have to do is incorrect.

Comment: My problem was described out of context i know, but i just needed to know how to perform that simpel task. The greater scope of my function is for a backbone app. I am creating multple collections with a for loop, and each collection needs 1 returned response, that increments when a new collection is created in the for loop.

I did get my answer, so even tho my question was taken out of the greater scope, they understood it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the keys of a `JSON` hash, there are two ways

```
// For the following object
var obj = {
  links_1: 'value1',
  links_2: 'value1',
  links_3: 'value1',
};

// key1 can be accessed like
console.log(obj.links_1);

// Or
console.log(obj['links_1']);
```

So, in your case, you can use the second method

```
var counter = 3;
for(var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
  return response['links_' + i];
}
```

Also, you can get the total count by

```
var counter = Object.keys(response).length;
```

And, if you don't need to do anything else with the `counter` variable, and the `response` object only contains the links, you can use something like

```
for (link in response) {
    return response[link];
}
```

Comment: Not sure i get that,

If i do it your way i get this error in console.

    ReferenceError: links_ is not defined

My desired parameter is response.links_1

Comment: i just needed to wrap the links_ in quotation marks, then it worked fine. 

return respose['links_' +1];

Answer (score 1):

You should try response["links_" + 3]

Answer (score 1):

The object dereference operator `.` doesn't work with dynamically generated property names, so you have to use the array dereference operator `[]` instead:

```
return response['links_' + i];
```